# Password and verification is true altough one of them is not set.

Tags: php, isset

i have some function for checking password is required and compare it with verification here's my function:

```
public function required($field= array())
    {
        foreach($field as $value) {
            if (isset($this->_input[$value])) {
                if (empty(Security::clean($this->_input[$value]))) {
                    $messages = "is Required.";
                    error::inputError($value, $messages);
                }
            } else{
                $messages = "Not Found.";
                error::inputError($field, $messages);

            }
        }
    }

    public function password($field, $confirmasion){
        if (isset($this->_input[$field] , $this->_input[$confirmasion])){
            if ($this->_input[$field] != $this->_input[$confirmasion])
            {
                $messages = "is different with $confirmasion.";
                error::inputError($field, $messages);
                error::inputError($confirmasion, $messages);

            }
        }
    }
```

In my class $this->_input refers to $_POST. and then i have a class to set an error like this:

```
public static function inputError($field, $messages)
    {
        if (is_array($field)) {
            foreach ($field as $key){
                $newName = General::changeName($key);
                $messagesError = "$newName $messages";
                if (isset(self::$_errors[$key])){
                    return;
                }else{
                    self::$_errors[$key] = $messagesError;
                }
            }
        }else{
            $newName = General::changeName($field);
            $messagesError = "$newName $messages";
            if (isset(self::$_errors[$field])){
                return;
            }else{
                self::$_errors[$field] = $messagesError;
            }
        }

    }
```

i'm expecting when when i submit form and my password and verification fields is empty it display "password is required" or "verification is required" only without showing error "password is different from verification”. but when i'm only fill my password fields it showing “verification is required“ and the second error "password is different different from verification” because my verification is still empty. Is it something wrong with my logic or something?

Comment: I'm down voting this because it is terrible security practice. password_verify and password_hash are the current standards

Comment: sorry i know that, i just haven't hashing it. it just my validation test.

Comment: @LuckyBurger i'm gonna hashing after it pass my validation. why u not asking before vote down?

Comment: @LuckyBurger  care to point out **exactly** where OP is using bad security practices? I can't see any persistence, just validation

Comment: @Kyo empty text fields still submit a value so `isset($this->_input['fieldname'])` will return `true`. Hence, having the *verification* field empty will still compare it to the password field. You may want to try `if (!empty($this->_input[$field]) && !empty($this->_input[$confirmasion]))` instead in your `password` function

Comment: so do you think i have to use empty rather then isset to check the value?

Comment: ok i will fix my code for a moment.

Comment: @Phil it seem you right, why not u put that in answer so i can choose your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
isset($this->_input['fieldname'])
```

this code will return true. Hence, having the verification field empty will still compare it to the password field.here's the solution:

```
(!empty($this->_input[$field]) && !empty($this->_input[$confirmasion]))
```